# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'apply'` when I try to return true from the callback function when usning jquery `.load()`. This makes me confused, why am I not allowed to return true?

```
$(function () {
    $("#myIdentifier").load("/some/url", {"someuselessdata" : 1, "moreuselessdata" :     1}, myHandlerFun());
});

function myHandlerFun () {
    console.log("Running handler function...");
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hms93twp/

This is *not* the case if I do a GET request like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#myIdentifier").load("/some/url", myHandlerFun());
});

function myHandlerFun () {
    console.log("Running handler function...");
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4hvczLkf/ or if I return false like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#myIdentifier").load("/some/url", {"someuselessdata" : 1, "moreuselessdata" :     1}, myHandlerFun());
});

function myHandlerFun () {
    console.log("Running handler function...");
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryvx36z1/

Comment: myHandlerFun is a callback why would you return something from it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Comment: @Donal I need to call myHandelFun manually from other functions that  evaluates the execution of myHandlerFun (ie differs between true/false on return). Ofc I can just wrap it into another function but that bothers me.